# Alternative to ampache

Tags: music

I currently use ampache (a web based music player), and most of it is great. However, looking at the commit graph on github it seems that development is slowing down considerably since more than a year now, and also there seems to be only one active developer.

To me this looks like a project that could be abandoned soon. So I am looking for alternatives.

Must have features:

- Web based

  - Accessible from multiple clients
  - Multiple users
- runs on my own Linux server
- local play - control music through browser but play through other device, e.g. an mpd server.
- Usable for large collection (500.000 files)
- Active development

Nice to have features

- User friendly interface (ampache is not great in this respect)
- Working mobile client (ampache has lots of mobile clients, none of which work)
- Open Source

  - Written in python

Answer (score 0):

I have been using **plex** now for 6+ years, and am quite happy with it. It does not fullfill all of the above noted requirements - most notably local play - however it does have a user friendly interface and a well maintained mobile client. Together with bluetooth audio it does what I need.